# How to change default homepage in Android browser?

Tags: browser

How to change address that appears in:
**Internet**(stock browser) -> **Settings** -> **Set home page** -> **Use default**.

I can set another homepage, or use current, but I'm interesting in changing exactly this field.

Comment: are you trying to do this programmatically or as a user?

Comment: trying to do as user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're in the browser, open the Menu, choose `More | Settings` and select "Set home page".

Comment: Ok, but I don't own that DTD with current issue. And I can't check on it.